# Printf shift error

Tags: c

I am working on Stm32f4xx , keil version 5 program

I want to use printf function with "A:float1 float2" format.

```
I want to float2 have to start 11.column.

    When float1=225.4 and float2=245.1: 
    A:225.4V  45.1A     
    When float1=0 and float2=0 
    A:0.0V    0.0A
```

My Codes-1:

```
char EA1[10]
char EA2[10]
CHAR line[20]

sprintf(EA1,"          ");
sprintf(EA1,"A:%3.1fV",float1);
sprintf(EA2,"%3.1fA    ",float2);
LCD_Set_Cursor(1,1)
printf(%s %s,EA1,EA2);
```

My Codes-2:

```
LCD_Set_Cursor(1,1);
printf("A:%3.1fV  ",float1);
LCD_Set_Cursor(11,1);
printf("%3.1fA    ",float2);
```

Output of mycodes-1 float2 start with 8 when float1=0 and float2=0

Output of mycodes-2 float2 is not working what I want. float2 Start sometimes 9.column sometimes 11.column

Comment: Probably I need a big coffee, but it is total unclear. Totally guessing: are you sure that your `printf` support `%f` format specifier?

Comment: I don't even what "Y shift left and right and mixed screen" ...

Comment: Please provide desired output *clearly* (show example of what you want)

Comment: So, If I understand correctly: `float2` must be printed starting from `column 11`: is it?

Comment: Yes. LPs you are right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can compose the string with fixed positions, like:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <string.h>

void printLine(char *s, size_t size, uint16_t position, float float1, float float2)
{
    if ((position > 0) && (position<size))
    {
        int index = 0;
        index += sprintf(s, "A:%3.1fV", float1);
        memset(&s[index], 0x20, size - index);
        sprintf(&s[position - 1], "%3.1fA", float2);

        printf("%s\n", s);
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    char LINE[128] = { 0 };

    printf("         1         2\n");
    printf("12345678901234567890\n");
    printLine(LINE, sizeof(LINE), 11, 225.4f, 41.5f);
    printLine(LINE, sizeof(LINE), 11, 0, 0);

    return 0;
}
```

OUTPUT

```
         1         2
12345678901234567890
A:225.4V  41.5A
A:0.0V    0.0A
```